# How to modify nth nested object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

Here's the original object data.

```
{
  "name": "animals",
  "children": [
    { "name": "mammals" },
    {
      "name": "reptile",
      "children": [
        { "name": "tortoise" },
        { "name": "snake", "children": [{ "name": "lizard" }] }
      ]
    },
    { "name": "birds" }
  ]
}
```

I have to add a new value to any children.

Provided arguments:

```
pathArrary : like ['animals', 'reptile', 'snake']
value: 'water snake'
```

Then `water snake` should be added as the last children of `snake`.

Target Object:

```
{
  "name": "animals",
  "children": [
    { "name": "mammals" },
    {
      "name": "reptile",
      "children": [
        { "name": "tortoise" },
        {
          "name": "snake",
          "children": [
            { "name": "lizard" }]
            { "name": "water snake" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    { "name": "birds" }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck? Please share your ideas, findings, code.

Comment: I did some research on StackOverflow and didn't find out the right answer. Still finding the best way to do it. @MrSmith42

Comment: Try something.  If that doesn't work, try something else.  If that doesn't work, and further research doesn't help, show us your best effort and explain what you think is still missing.  People will be glad to help if you put the effort in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to the above question.

```
const addNewPropToObj = (obj, path, value, depth) => {
  const hasChildren = "children" in obj;

  if (!hasChildren) {
    return {
      ...obj,
      children: [{ name: value }],
    };
  }

  let children = obj.children;
  const activeIdx = children.findIndex(
    (item) => item.name === path[path.length - depth]
  );

  if (depth > 0)
    children[activeIdx] = addNewPropToObj(
      children[activeIdx],
      path.slice(1),
      value,
      depth - 1
    );
  else children = [...children, { name: value }];

  return {
    ...obj,
    children,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another take on it:

```js
const data={
  "name": "animals",
  "children": [
{ "name": "mammals" },
{
  "name": "reptile",
  "children": [
    {

 "name": "tortoise" },
    { "name": "snake", "children": [{ "name": "lizard" }] }
  ]
},
{ "name": "birds" }
  ]
},
 trgt=['animals','reptile','snake'],
 val='water snake';

function get(obj,keys){
  const ob=obj?.children.find(v=>v.name==keys[0]??"");
  if(ob&&keys.length>1) return get(ob,keys.slice(1));
  else return ob;
}

console.log(get({children:[data]},trgt)?.children.push({name:"water snake"})?"success:":"failure:",data);
```

The conditional chain expression `?.children` in the script helps to avoid throwing an error in case of certain parts of the address path not being found. They will then return an `undefined` value which can be used to make further decisions, like abandoning the search itself or returning a "failure" message when trying to add another value to it.